# Check if a subset exists in SQL

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    Order_ID int,
    Product_ID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(Order_ID,Product_ID)
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (3,3), (3,4);
```

Each order has a set of products; how do I get all orders which have the product set of the order 2 as a subset of their product sets?

I want to get as results

```
OrderID
--
 1
 2
```

For further understanding:

In the example: The order 2 has products {2,3}

The result must be orders 1 and 2, because the order 1 has products {1,2,3} — it has subset {2,3}. On the other hand, the order 3's product set is {3,4} — it doesn't have subset {2,3}, so it must not returned in the result.

Comment: I made that question, too. By the time i refreshed it, was already closed so I made one new

Comment: I know you did. But your new question doesn't contain any more information than the old one - why do you think the old one was close? And you again didn't bother to format it properly.

Comment: the old question did not contained the last 7 lines. I changed the question after it was closed so the refresehd question had no use.

Comment: But the *actual* question which Inflane was trying to ask is pretty reasonable.

Comment: @Inflane : your question have been reopened. I've tried to merge the two for a better understanding, and I answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Order_ID 
FROM Orders T1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT Product_ID 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE Order_ID = 2
  EXCEPT
    SELECT Product_ID 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE Order_ID = T1.Order_ID);
```

Okay, that's probably not the most efficient way, but hey! The DBMS will have to look at every row anyway.

Comment: Very nice this is what I want. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this I think

```
select distinct orderid
from table_name
where product_id in ALL (select product_id from table_name where orderid = 2)
```

Comment: this one has some trouble with the syndax. "in ALL" is not valid